# Web MVC framework for bridging front-end access to Go-lang back-end REST API

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, go, web-config, web-frameworks

I want to use ReactJS for the front-end and Go for back-end. But both of these technologies is not a web mvc framework.
What mvc framework can i have to use to provide capabilities like routing an accessing the backend Go API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reactjs and go together, and many people have. You may want to check out something like this [go react starter kit](https://github.com/olebedev/go-starter-kit/blob/master/server/main.go) although that seems pretty complicated.

MVC is not really a thing you hear about terribly often in go apps. You really just need a rest api that exposes your data. You can build that with the standard library, or use a simple framework like [gorilla](https://github.com/gorilla/mux).

Comment: Sorry for the  late comment ... but How can I then consume the API rest using ReactJs?